# How do I accept two different types of network connections using iptables

Tags: iptables, unix, mongodb

I need to setup iptables for a mongodb database server, such that it allows only two types of INPUT connections:

1. one connection to port 27017, monogdb's default port, from our main web-app
2. one ssh connection from my main network, which has a different IP address from our web-app

The issue is that these rules needs to be chained.

Here's what I tried:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -j ACCEPT # allows all connections via ssh (port 22)

iptables -A INPUT -s web-app-IP -p tcp --destination-port 27017 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -d web-app-IP -p tcp --source-port 27017 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

The first line allows all incoming connections on port 22, while the second and third lines allow all connections from thw web-app-IP to and from the mongodb server only.

It seems that the first line is getting blocked by the second and third line. Is there a logical OR operator for iptables? If not, how do I setup the rules to allow for both of these types of connections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not allowing ESTABLISHED connections out from ssh.  I'd go with a slightly simpler:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 22 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s web-app-IP -p tcp --destination-port 27017 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

Comment: Also, you might want to allow some ICMP in/out, but that's out of scope for this!

Comment: Could you please explain this line: `iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` in particular, I don't understand the `-m` flag and what does it mean to be `ESTABLISHED` ? Thanks

Comment: `-m state` means "load the state module" (which is where we get --state from).  The `ESTABLISHED` state is packets in a tcp session we've already allowed (which we did with `--state NEW` on the ssh and 27017 lines)